# Database unclosed cursor. Close it after insert method

Tags: android, database

Would you mind pointing out what's wrong with this peace of code. genresCursor contains  "Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here" exception. How do I really close this cursor after inserting ? 
Thanks.

UPD: It seems like there wasn't a problem at all. Even though it contains exception that's still possible to extract data. I must've been wrong in my real application and this exception  led me to conclusion that's it  had been the issue. Thanks everyone for participating.

```
public class DatabaseCursorActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        HashMap<Integer, String> _dummy = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        OpenDatabaseHelper helper = new OpenDatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(OpenDatabaseHelper.GENRES_ID_KEY, 1);
        values.put(OpenDatabaseHelper.GENRES_TITLE_KEY, "Test");
        db.insert(OpenDatabaseHelper.GENRES_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
        helper.close();

        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor genresCursor = db.query(OpenDatabaseHelper.GENRES_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{OpenDatabaseHelper.GENRES_ID_KEY, OpenDatabaseHelper.GENRES_TITLE_KEY }, null, null, null, null, null);
        int i = genresCursor.getColumnCount();
        genresCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    public class OpenDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String GENRES_TABLE_NAME = "genres";
        public static final String GENRES_ID_KEY = "id";
        public static final String GENRES_TITLE_KEY = "title";

        public OpenDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "ttt.db", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + GENRES_TABLE_NAME + "( id integer primary key not null, title text);" );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Stop closing your `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `SQLiteDatabase` immediately - do that in `Activity#onDestroy()` or something similar (i.e. at the end of your activitys life cycle). Start closing your `Cursor`s or begin using `Activity#startManagingCursor`

Comment: it's a desperate act, but I used everything I could to close this insert -cursor. So can you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the database first and after inserting you closed the database and then opened again to read the value.

First thing you don't need to close and open it again.You can do all of your operation and can close it as you are still in same block of code.

After doing the operation with your genresCursor close it by by genresCursor.close() and then close your db.Hopefully it will be fine.

Comment: you guys are way too theoretical. What you've just said is ofc right, but in this particular example it's doesn't make any difference. So, after inserting I need to close the cursor - can you help me with it ? You can cope-paste code and try it on your own

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you insert this code:

```
db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor genresCursor = db.query(OpenDatabaseHelper.GENRES_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{OpenDatabaseHelper.GENRES_ID_KEY, OpenDatabaseHelper.GENRES_TITLE_KEY }, null, null, null, null, null);
int i = genresCursor.getColumnCount();
genresCursor.moveToFirst();
```

The problem is in this part of code. If you just want to close cursor then call `genresCursor.close()`. But from the architecture point of view I do not understand why you need this code.

Comment: Nope, it's not there. If you debug and watch genreCursor you'll see an  exception message inside, that I've posted above. So the problem is that it's actually after insert when the cursor should be closed. But I don't know how to accomplish that. Writing/reading might not have sense here, but between activites it does matter.

Comment: You can just comment this piece of code and check. I guess the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Practice to work with cursor and database is that you should open it and close it in the same block of code. When I use to insert rows into database I use to open it at start and then insert many column and close it just before returning.

In API before Honeycomb you wont get any log message and performance issue regarding unclosed cursor but API before Honeycomb has a Cursor not closed detector which will log message about cursor not being closed.

Edit:
Close Database within same block of code. Cursor can be closed as per the scenario but must be closed before Context Deletion.